# How do I make a variable containing two tuples go into SQLite3 table?

Tags: python, sqlite, web-scraping

So I have scraped some venue names and addresses from a website, I'd now like to add them both to a database table using a function.

Unfortunately, I get the `incorrect bindings` error whenever I try doing this with more than one set of elements. The code works when I am just filling one column, but now I am trying to fill both it isn't working. I am wondering if it is to do with how I've constructed the `testsuburb` variable which contains two tuples as a tuple... I've been following along with this [tutorial](https://pynative.com/python-sqlite-insert-into-table/) (the relevant part is towards the bottom) but they use manually entered data and I am trying to use scraped data.

I'd appreciate any guidance!

Here's the webscraping code:

```
#cafeNames
url = 'https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-thornbury' #go to the website
response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)

soup_cafe_names = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
type(soup_cafe_names)

cafeNames = soup_cafe_names.findAll('h2', attrs={"class":"venue-title", }) #scrape the elements
cafeNamesClean = [cafe.text.strip() for cafe in cafeNames] #clean the elements
cafeNameTuple = [(cafe,) for cafe in cafeNamesClean]

#addresses
soup_cafe_addresses = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
type(soup_cafe_addresses)

cafeAddresses = soup_cafe_addresses.findAll( attrs={"class":"address-content" })
cafeAddressesClean = [address.text for address in cafeAddresses]
cafeAddressesTuple = [(address,) for address in cafeAddressesClean]

#suburbtuple
testsuburb = [(cafeNameTuple), (cafeAddressesTuple)]

print(testsuburb)
```

And here is the function:

```
##enter data into table
def insertnames(suburb):
    try:
        sqlite_insert_name_param = """INSERT INTO Thornbury
                            (name, address)
                            VALUES (?,?);"""

        cursor.executemany(sqlite_insert_name_param, suburb)

        sqliteConnection.commit()
        print("Total", cursor.rowcount, "Records inserted successfully into table")
        sqliteConnection.commit()

        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Failed to insert data into sqlite table", error)

    finally:
        if (sqliteConnection):
            sqliteConnection.close()
            print("The SQLite connection is closed")

insertnames(testsuburb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a list of lists of (single-element) tuples; one level too many, and in the opposite shape.

What you probably want is: `suburb = zip(cafeNamesClean, cafeAddressesClean)`

Comment: Thank you so much! Can I just ask for my own learning. I tried the zip method but with the tuple() added but if failed. How does your version work?

Comment: Have a play with it with a few short lists? `print(zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]))` and various variants with tuples in various places?